# Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

Tags: database

I have no problems using the dashboard, viewing plugins, etc. but when I try to view the front end I get

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

WP can obviously get to the database because I can view the dashboard and back end. What could the problem be?

Comment: Is this a server you control or shared hosting? mitigating this might have different solutions depending...

Comment: What does your hosting company say? Mine has a one-click option to set up WordPress (plus very helpful support; it's what you pay for. Did you ask them?).